# how remove flutter web native splash screen when add to phone home?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

when flutter PWA added to home it has default splash screen with blue color and logo I want to remove that , where is it?

Answer (score 0):

The default splash screen cannot be `overridden`. They are controls shown by the native Android/iOS context while the Flutter runtime is initializing and that splash is default by `flutter pwa`.

in simple words while Android/iOS loads environment to run your web app at that time this screen is shown and for now there is no way to change or replace it. and you splash set for web also appear after default screen.

Answer (score 0):

The native Flutter splash screen cannot be removed, only changed. I maintain a package that allows you to change the native splash screen: [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) .